# Rails 3: Complex Create Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, nested-forms

I have a nested form which is submitting through a create function in my 'Posts' controller. One Post has many Locations. My problem is I want to set locations up to 'Find_Or_Create_by_name' but not posts.

I figure something like this is a solution:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])    
  @post.locations = Location.find_or_create_by_name(params[:post])

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

But I get an 'each' error.

```
 undefined method `each' for #<Location:0x007fc5c1c2e5c8>
```

Am I on the right track with this? What's the next step? Should I be iterating through each 'location'?

Any help would be great.

EDIT: Here's the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     authenticity_token"=>"Ffk65s3/aZqVcBvh9S/hOt7zYSighzyt6CSNDIuNt1Q=", "post"=>{"title"=>"This
  is about London", "body"=>"This is about London", "tag_list"=>"", "locations_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"London", "longitude"=>"-0.1276831", "la
  titude"=>"51.5073346"}}}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "name"=>"London", "legname"=>"London",
 "longitude"=>"-0.1276831", "latitude"=>"51.5073346", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: does your `post has many locations` or `post has one location`

Comment: If you are doing multiple locations you'll need to use the syntax: @post.locations << Location.find_or_create_by_name(params[:post])

Comment: Rahul, My post `has_and_belongs_to_many` locations. 

@EricC, Thanks for this but weirdly this appears to add the first row in my 'locations' table to the post and create a new entry for the location I actually want. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you passed wrong parameter, you create new location but you pass `params[:post]`? Do you used `accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations`? If yes, maybe params you should pass is `params[:post][:locations_attributes]['0'][:name]` . I suppose Location model has `name` column. Or maybe you should show your view rendered html for more info to help.

Comment: Hi @KienThanh, Thanks for this. The problem with this is it will only submit one of many of my nested locations. I will add the `:post` log above, that may help?

Comment: What do you mean `only submit one of many of my nested locations`?

Comment: Each post is submitting many locations using a nested form. You are right in that I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations`, however if I put `@post.locations << Location.find_or_create_by_name(params[:post][:locations_attributes]['0'][:name])` only the first nested value will be created, right?

Comment: You can loop over nested object like: `params[:post][:locations_attributes].each do |order, params| @post.locations = Location.find_or_create_by_name(params[:name]) end`

Comment: Ah, you should use `@post.locations.build = Location.where(name: params[:name]).first_or_initialize` , because at this time, your @post has not saved yet.

Comment: Hi @KienThanh, Thanks so much for all your help on this! The first suggested loop brings up an `'each'` method error. The second suggestion, using 'build' gives me `undefined method 'build=' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`, without build I get the `'each'` error again. Any other ideas? It feels we're so close to this!

Comment: It gets a bit closer by using `@post.locations << Location.where(name: params[:name]).first_or_initialize` without `Build`. It then appears to find the first location but also create a new one. This means the same locations appears next to the post twice.

Comment: Just FYI too `@post.locations.where(:name=> params[:name]).first_or_initialize` works but always creates a new entry. It does not find the first...

Comment: This's not what you want: `@post.locations.where(:name=> params[:name]).first_or_initialize` because it just find locations of post, not all location. I think this code work: `@post.locations << Location.where(name: params[:name]).first_or_initialize`, because `first_or_initialize` method will find a location with name, if Location don't have this record, it will initialize a new location. If Location has a record, it will return that record. Check again. Can you please post your result, SQL when run this code on your question for more info?

Comment: Hi! Thanks again for all your help. I figured out why I was encountering the above problem with `@post.locations << Location.where(name: params[:name]).first_or_initialize`, it was unrelated. My problem with this is, it only checks the first location but there can be many submitted. I'm guessing I should run an `each` statement on my params but not sure the best way to execute this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Location model

```
def self.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set)
  locations = []
  location_set.each do |key, location|
    locations << find_or_initialize_by_name location
  end
  locations
end
```

Then in your create action

```
def create
  location_set = params[:post].delete(:locations_attributes) unless params[:post][:locations_attributes].blank?
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])
  @post.locations = Location.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set) unless location_set.nil?
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
```

end

Comment: Hi there! I had to change to this line in the model statement `locations << find_or_initialize_by_name (location)` and then getting this error: `undefined method 'find_or_initialize_location_set' for #<Class:0x007f8f7526bec8>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. function definition should be def self.find_or_initialize_location_set